# Generic function to convert a cv::Mat into std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, templates

I am wondering if there is a generic approach to convert any cv::Mat to a std::vector. 
For specific types e.g. uchar I can to something like:

```cpp
std::vector<uchar> convert(const cv::Ma& mat)
{
std::vector<uchar> array;
if (mat.isContinuous()) {
  array.assign(mat.data, mat.data + mat.total());
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
    array.insert(array.end(), mat.ptr<uchar>(i), mat.ptr<uchar>(i)+mat.cols);
  }
}
return array;
}
```

However, I would like to avoid duplicating my code for different types and have something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> convert(const cv::Mat_<T>& mat)
{
std::vector<T> array;
if (mat.isContinuous()) {
  array.assign(mat.data, mat.data + mat.total());
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
    array.insert(array.end(), mat.ptr(i), mat.ptr(i)+mat.cols);
  }
}
}
```

Which doesn't work since cv::Mat is templated over cv::Vec4f for instance. 
Of course I could do now something like

```cpp
template<typename T, int C>
std::vector<T> convert(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<T,C>>& mat)
```

.. but for this I get an error message: `note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Mat_<Vec<type-parameter-0-0, cn> >' against 'cv::Mat'`

Comment: Matrix of scalars and matrix of vectors are different things. How would you like to convert the latter into a vector?

Comment: Yes, that is true that these are different things, but still they can be arranged into a single vector of scalars of size rows\*cols\*depth.

Comment: So you want to "flatten" the matrix of vectors? Do you need a generalization to a matrix of matrices, for example?

Comment: Exactly, I want to flatten it. Hmm, well the input is kind of a matrix of matrices if we consider the vectors as a <X,1> matrix. Why are you asking?

Comment: With templates you can write a very general solution. So I want to understand whether you need it or `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<T,C>>` is the only type you care about.

Comment: Yes, this is the only type I care about.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept any `Mat` and constraint it using SFINAE.

For example:

```
template<class Mat, std::enable_if_t<
         std::is_arithmetic_v<typename Mat::value_type>, int> = 0>
auto convert(const Mat& mat) {
    using T = typename Mat::value_type;
    std::vector<T> arr;
    // ...
    return arr;
}

template<class Mat, std::enable_if_t<
         std::is_arithmetic_v<typename Mat::value_type::value_type>, int> = 0>
auto convert(const Mat& mat) {
    using T = typename Mat::value_type::value_type;
    constexpr auto channels = typename Mat::value_type::channels; // = C
    std::vector<T> arr;
    // ...
    return arr;
}
```

The first function will accept `cv::Mat_<T>` with any arithmetic `T`. The second one will accept `cv::Mat_<T>` with any `T` such that `T::value_type` is a valid type that is arithmetic (e.g., `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec4f>`).

You can add more constraints using SFINAE if needed.

Comment: Ok, I see where this is going. And yes, this is very helpful. But it doesn't yet quite work as I get a ` candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Mat = cv::Mat]: no member named 'value_type' in 'cv::Mat'`

Comment: @Simon, for `cv::Mat` you need a separate overload, because it doesn't have `value_type` member type. `cv::Mat` and `cv::Mat_<T>` are quite different in that respect.

Comment: @Simon For example, you can have first overload that takes `cv::Mat` and the second one that takes `cv::Mat_`. The second overload can then call another function that has two overloads, one for arithmetic type, another one for `cv::Vec` type.

Comment: @Simon, note that `cv::Mat` cannot be templated over `cv::Vec4f`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Ok, then this now goes more into a OpenCV related question. How can I get the type of a *cv::Mat* --- or how to get from cv::Mat to cv::Mat_ for which I can than use value_type

Comment: @Simon You can't do it directly. You need additional information about the element type (`T`). `Mat` has a `type()` member function that returns type as an `int`, such that `DataType<T>::type` is equal to it (`Mat_` will pass `DataType<T>::type` to `Mat` inside the constructor). You can't simply "invert" `DataType` because `T` is a compile-time quantity, but `type()` is run-time. What you can do is to write some template function and call it in a series of `if` statements, one for each supported data type. If you have some constraints on the types, it can be reasonably simplified.